# Как правильно установить C на Windows 10?

Tags: c, windows, компилятор

Хочу разработать несколько простых программ (калькулятор, текстовый редактор) на C (именно C, а не  C++) под Windows 7/10/11. Какой компилятор и как установить?

P.S. Разнообразие компиляторов для C меня сбило с толку :)

Comment: Ставьте Visual Studio 2022

Comment: @user7860670, я в вопросе указал, что мне нужен только компилятор C (хочу писать код в Visual Studio Code, а компилировать в терминале). Профессиональную IDE для создания простого калькулятора скачивать не планирую :)
Можно ли установить C, не скачивая Visual Studio 2022?

Comment: Visual Studio Code выходит тяжелее, чем Visual Studio и сложнее в использовании, особенно для новичков (вопросы по ней тут сыпятся регулярно). Но если интересно, то можно скачать и просто компилятор - Visual Studio Build Tools + Windows SDK.

Comment: [C/C++ for Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp) - описана установка компилятора.

Comment: Если нужен именно Си, не связывайтесь с продукцией MS - они не знают, что Си развивается и для него выходят новые стандарты. Смотрите в сторону реализаций gcc (mingw). Как вариант, под Windows можно установить  MSYS2, а в нем через пакетный менеджер можно установить не только нужный компилятор, но и огромное количество библиотек из среды юниксов. Ну или, если кроме языка ничего не нужно, то еще можете посмотреть на [Pelles C](http://www.smorgasbordet.com/pellesc/) - это компактная среда разработки для одного языка и компилятор Си, который поддерживает стандарты до C17 (если не обманывают).

Comment: @Vladimir Тогда можно посоветовать не связываться с вашими комментариями, так как вы не в курсе, что продукция MS развивается и поддерживает актуальные стандарты С.

Comment: @user7860670, если Вы так хорошо знаете MS VS, скажите, туда уже завезли VLA массивы? И поддержку вывода типа size_t в `printf()` (модификатор z)? Я не смог обнаружить ничего этого поддерживаемым. Зато ключи c11 и c17 у них  есть, да: [Соответствие стандартам языка Microsoft C/C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=msvc-170)

Comment: @Vladimir Модификатор `z` в `printf` поддерживается. VLA массивов к счастью нет и не будет, благо они теперь относятся к категории необязательных расширений.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. установите gcc(mingw) (в том же комплекте есть g++ для с++, gcc именно для си)\

   mingw gcc в гугле - первая ссылка/downloads [mingw-w64.org/downloads](https://mingw-w64.org/downloads) (w64devkit он там называется, не пугайтесь что там написано c,c++, fortran там будет несколько РАЗНЫХ компиляторов) Там находите вашу ОС(Windows), качаете, открываете и устанавливаете в удобную, для вас, папку (компиляторы скорее всего после установки будут в папке bin(а папка bin внутри той папки, куда вы установите весь этот пакет))
2. добавьте в path путь где лежит установленный gcc\

   Гуглите как добавить пременную среды path (это нужно для того, чтобы вам каждый раз не приходилось при вызове gcc писать путь к нему, а ос сама знала где надо смотреть в первую очередь ) и добавляете в path путь до папки, где будет лежать установленный gcc.exe
3. в консоли `cd /MyProj/` - перейдите в папку со своим кодом

   `gcc main.c -oprog.exe`

Получаете `prog.exe` и запускаете : `prog.exe` или просто `prog`

По поводу редакторов кода - посмотрите `sublime-text3`, очень хороший и легкий, красивый и не будет замыливать вам глаза лишней информацией.

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, дать более подробную инструкцию? Например: "установите gcc(mingw)" - откуда его взять и какую версию?

Comment: @ДмитрийКраснов 

1) mingw gcc в гугле - первая ссылка/downloads https://www.mingw-w64.org/downloads/
Там находите вашу ОС(Windows), качаете, открываете и устанавливаете в удобную, для вас, папку

2) Гуглите как добавить пременную среды path (это нужно для того, чтобы вам каждый раз не приходилось при вызове gcc писать путь к нему, а ос сама знала где надо смотреть в первую очередь ) и добавляете в path путь до папки, где будет лежать установленный gcc.exe 

3) из предыдущего сообщения

Comment: @ДмитрийКраснов w64devkit он там называется, не пугайтесь что там написано c,c++, fortran там будет несколько РАЗНЫХ компиляторов, скорее всего после установки они будут в папке bin(а папка bin внутри той папки, куда вы установите весь этот пакет)

Comment: SpaceResearcher, установил. Спасибо Вам!

Comment: SpaceResearcher, на этом сайте (https://metanit.com/cpp/c/1.2.php) предлагают установить какой-то MSYS2. Он подойдёт?

Comment: @ДмитрийКраснов это не принципиально, вам подойдет любой пакет, где есть gcc. В msys2 он как раз есть и инструкция по добавлению пути в path там тоже есть. В общем не важно, какой пакет программ вы скачаете, главное чтобы там был сам компилятор GCC и вы праильно прописали PATH

Answer (score 0):

visual studio 2022
в начале установки можно выбрать все необходимые языки
сам пытался установить отдельно с++, из всех результатов только этот подошел, все скачалось и можно спокойно писать на языке
по интерфейсу он схож с visual studio code, там нет ничего сложного
удачи

Comment: Спасибо, но я в вопросе указал: мне нужен только компилятор, а не профессиональная IDE. По интерфейсу Visual Studio 2022 действительно проста, однако дело не в этом. У меня достаточно слабый ноутбук и Visual Studio 2022 на нём подвисает.

Comment: Честно, я не знаю, что можно порекомендовать, только если скачать ее, только ранних версий